# What is the OOP reasoning behind the design of XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I looked up `System.Xml.XmlWriter` class and i noticed it is an abstract call class and you have to create new object with the Create method and I was wondering what was the OOP reasoning behind this and why wouldn't `XmlWriter` be designed more like the classes from `System.IO`.

Comment: You may want to ask Microsoft that question.

Comment: I disagree with the *close* vote. Answers to this question can very well be "supported by facts, references, or specific expertise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) is an abstract base class for classes that can write Xml documents. In the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), you can see that various classes are derived from `XmlWriter` that write Xml to various destinations. `XmlWriter` itself just defines the public interface and some superficial implementation for Xml writers.

This is analogous to the [abstract `TextWriter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx).

The static `Create` methods seem to exist because for certain situations (e.g. writing to a file), a particular subclass is recommended. That subclass is instantiated by the respective `Create` method.

Note that `XmlWriter.Create` for writing to a file does not necessarily create an [`XmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx). The .NET framework code might decide that a different (possibly internal) type is more appropriate for your particular environment and settings. As you call the static `Create` method, you do not have to care about which type is actually instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in practice and is used when you wish to abstract away the decision of what implementation of an interface or base class should be constructed.

In this case from what I can see by inspecting the IL when you use `XmlWriter.Create` the method has a number of possible different internal types, e.g. `XmlUtf8RawTextWriterIndent` or `HtmlUtf8RawTextWriter` to choose from - you need to use the `Create` method to create these classes firstly because these types are internal (and therefore you cannot invoke their constructors directly) and also because it is the `Create` method that contains the logic around which writer should be created in what scenario.

Answer (score 1):

you use abstract classes when you want to share certain implementation details with all derived classes yet don't allow the users to simply istantiate and use your base abstract class directly.

an interface is a pure abstract class, which means all methods and fields should be implemented by the classes implementing that interface so there is no code re-use at all except than methods / properties signatures.

for `System.IO` classes, most likely you are looking at classes like `Path`, `File`, `Directory`, I see no much to abstract in there since all files are the same, all directories are the same etc, while the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) is generic and depending on specific cases, derived concrete classes will implement the required specializations case by case.

Comment: answers from JaredPar and from Justin are more specific to your question in this case, my answer is more generic about abstract classes vs interfaces and does not answer your specific question. Still leaving my answer here, once is there...

Answer (score 1):

one way to understand the reason is to look at the set of virtual methods and types that derive from `XmlWriter`.  Pretty much all of the virtual methods are of the `Write` variety.  A quick look in reflector shows over 10 derived types including ones that

- Write the output in a standard text way
- Do Utf8 specific encoding tricks
- Write the output asynchronously
- Write + format the output

Based on this the primary reason for making it an abstract class is to allow developers to customize the output and manner in which the output is written